# jquery.height() hangs in IE after appending to the DOM

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a page which dynamically fetches text content from the server, using jquery to append it into the dom and then doing some further processing (jquery 'height()' among others) so that we can potentially scroll /resize / etc.  In this scenario the text I'm fetching back has a ton of whitespaces - it comes from a spreadsheet which has been converted to text, the first line is a header line which is 66393 characters long (on one line!).  Total size of the file containing this text is less than 1Meg, so easily viewable in a text editor though the horizontal scrollbar is tiny!

For this scenario, IE8, IE9, IE10, and IE11 freeze (spinning icons stop spinning, window turns white) on the line indicated below:

```
var chunks = $('#textChunks');
var h1 = chunks.height();
console.log("h1 = " + h1);
chunks.append(newContent);
console.log("content appended");
var h2 = chunks.height();//IE Hangs on this line!
console.log("h2 = " + h2);

//note that I can use javascript append like:
//element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", newContent);
//and IE still dies on the same line
```

I have added console.log statements for illustration which are not normally in the code.  If I comment out the append() call, IE happily continues processing, so **it's the combination of appending to the DOM and then taking another jquery.height() which is freezing IE** for me, for this particular content!

The page works fine otherwise, it's been in production for more than a year, tested in all major browsers, and I just upgraded the jquery libraries to 1.9.2 for testing this issue (which did not fix the issue).

The 'newContent' variable contains a string of plain text wrapped with a span tag, like this:  <span id='foo1'>plain text here</span>

If this doesn't ring a bell with someone, I will try to post some sanitized content or something.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear, when it *"hangs"* (whatever that means), you're getting the `console.log("content appended")` before it hangs?

Comment: If you don't call `chunks.height()` it "hangs"? I think you need to wait for IE to finish appending the content, try putting a little timeout before calling `chunks.height()`

Comment: What exactly is the HTML in `newContent`?

Comment: when I say "hangs" or "freezes"... yes, the console output "content appended" appears immediately. In non-IE browsers, the console output line h2 follows immediately, but in IE the browser immediately becomes unresponsive (spinning graphics stop spinning, and the whole window turns white, taskBar icon says "non-reponsive" and i never see the h2 output).

Comment: updated original post to give more info about 'newContent' which is a plaintext string wrapped with a <span> tag.

Answer (score 0):

What rings a bell for me is that IE trips up on certain types of content creation through jQuery.  So `chunks.append(newContent);` could be causing a problem for certain type of HTML in `newContent` and, if I recall correctly, the issue has to do with how jQuery creates a temporary fragment for the new content before inserting it and there are some bugs in IE related to that.

You can work-around it by changing the way you append the `newContent` (I'll have to do some research to find those specifics).  It turns out there are several different issues with `.append()` in IE and which work-around is appropriate depends upon the content you are appending.  If you can create a jsFiddle that illustrates the issue with your actual content, we can likely offer a work-around.

Comment: including a doctype for example has caused memory leaks in the past if not first passed through `$.parseHTML`

Comment: thanks for the idea!!!  however, i replaced the jquery.append() call with this:  element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", newContent);  and Still i see the same issue!  My console.log statement "content appended" appears quickly, and the "h2" console.log statement never shows up as the browser hangs immediately.

Comment: also just tried the append with element.innerHTML and still the 'freeze' happens at the same place

Comment: updated original post to indicate the new information gained by your suggestion about different .append() methods, thx again